# Spring Rest api and Spring Basic Security

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hello I am new in spring and spring security. currently i am working on rest api in spring. as per spring provide rest api. rest api are stateless so we can not create a session to rest api. because it's a stateless if we do so then it's against the rest design. so my question is that can **we never maintain the state of user in server side in rest?** **can we maintain it client side?? How??**
In spring basic security we logged in and get the current user using principle. same case in spring rest authentication. so in **case of rest api all is need is currently logged user?**.if the spring rest api is stateless then how spring security maintain the currently logged in user. I read some block about spring through which we use token based authentication in which we can send username and password then we get the token and every time when we request we send that token and know the user which send the current request. the token is stored in cookie. So the cookie is stored in client side. In that case if the browser disable the cookies the **how can we authenticate user and current user who logged in?**

Comment: In a true RESTful environment there is no log-in, you just provide the user credentials and password in each request via the `Authorization` header. In Spring security you can i.e. add an `basicAuth()` directive which checks an incoming request for the availability of this header and also that its value matches `Basic ${base64enc(username:password)}` where it will decode the base64 value and split the credentials in order to lookup the user from the user details service and add it to the security context where you can access it

Comment: so is spring security do all work for use in that case?

Comment: depends on your needs. In theory it can though I usually tend to at least provide a custom UserDetailsService and a AuthenticationProvider as I enrich the actual UserDetails object with domain specific properties and settings.

Answer (score 1):

REST has nothing to do with security as is, its all about data manipulation, not about a security.

So, usually, you supply some sort of identification information along with your REST request. It can be a set of credentials, a token, an encrypted token and what not. For example, one of the formats of tokens is JWT token. But in theory, you can work with different formats as well.

Spring security supports many different flows. Sometimes you'll have to extend it here and there and plug-in some capabilities. But all in all, spring security is very extensible and allows many different levels of flexibility, its designed to support many different flows.

I know it's a kind of theoretical answer, but the question is also pretty theoretical :)

Comment: REST isn't about data manipulation its about decoupling clients from servers and hence improving robustness of the architecture by relying on common and well accepted standards like HTTP, which is used to hande resource manipulation operations according to its protocol definition.